# Craft 2 CMS - How to change Limits in Dashboard

Tags: craft2

I'm very new to Craft CMS.

The company I work for, has their website build with Craft. The website was build by a 3rd party company, Now they gave me the responsibility to give the site a facelift.

Currently I'm struggling to increase the limit of services displaying on the home page.

We have 4 services, but only 3 display.

In the back end of Craft Dashboard, I can only assign 3 services, can I increase this to 4?

And if I can, how can I do it?

Looking forward to some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If the account you're using has admin rights you could do so by going to:
Settings > Fields > [Field label of your service display] and edit it. On the bottom there should be a input which sets the limit of your displays to 3.

You should only check with the person who build your website if they didnt set the limit in the code to 3. If so he has to change that.